# Proving the set of limit (adherent) points equals the closure.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**DEFINITION:** The closure of $A$ in a metric space is $\overline A := \bigcap \{C : C \text{ is closed and } A \subset C \}$.

**DEFINITION:** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. We say $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if for all open subsets $U$ such that $x \in U$, $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$. (Sometimes, this is called an "adherent point", but I am using the word "limit point.")

**LEMMA:** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then $x\in X$ is a limit point of $A \subset X$ if and only if there exists $(x_n)$ in $A$ (that is, each $x_n \in A$) such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = x$.

**CLAIM:** Let $$\overline A' = \{\text{limit pts of A in }(X,d) \}.$$
Then $\overline A = \overline A'$.

**PROOF:**
$(\subset)$ We claim $\overline A'$ is closed. Let $y \in X \backslash \overline A'$. Then $y$ is not a limit point of $A$. By the Lemma for all $(x_n) \in A$, there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for all $N_1 \in \mathbb N$, there exists (STAR) $n \geq N_1$ such that $d(x_n, y) \geq \epsilon_0$. We claim $B_{\epsilon_0 / 2} (y) \subset X \backslash \overline A'$. For contradiction suppose there exists $z \in B_{\epsilon_0 / 2}(y)$ such that $z \not\in X \backslash \overline A'$. Then $d(z,y) < \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$ and by Lemma, there exists $(x_n) \in A$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_2$ such that for all $n \geq N_2$, $d(x_n, z) < \epsilon$. Pick any $N_1 \in \mathbb N$. Then by (STAR), there exists $n_1$ such that $d(x_{n_1}, y) \geq \epsilon_0$. But then when $\epsilon = \epsilon_0$ and $m = \max \{ n_1, N_2 \}$, then
$$d(x_m, z) < \epsilon_0 / 2 \text{ and } d(x_m, y) \geq \epsilon_0.$$
Recall $d(z,y) < \epsilon_0 / 2$. By the Triangle Inequality,
$$d(x_m, y) \leq d(x_m, z) + d(z,y) < \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} = \epsilon_0$$
which contradicts $d(x_m, y) \geq \epsilon_0.$ Thus, $X \backslash \overline A'$ is open, so $\overline A'$ is closed, and since $\overline A$ is the smallest closed set, $\overline A \subset \overline A'$.

$(\supset)$ Let $x \in \overline A'$. By the Lemma, there exists $(x_n) \in A$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. But then $(x_n) \in \overline A$, which is closed, so $x \in \overline A$.
**END OF PROOF**

Is the above proof correct?

Comment: Check the statement of your LEMMA.

Comment: Your definition of "limit point" is not standard. A *limit point* $x$ of a set $A \subseteq X$ is such that every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $A$ at a point *other than $x$ itself* - that is, $x \in \text{Cl} (A - \{ x \})$. Your definition is for an *adherent* point, which is different from a *limit* point, and it is easy to show that the set of adherent points is exactly the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you understand that the commonly-accepted definitions of "limit point" and "adherent point" are not the same. An "adherent point" $x$ of a set $A$ is such that every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $A$. A "limit point" $x$ of a set $A$ is such that every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $A$ at a point other than $x$ itself. The definition you provided is for an "adherent point", so we will instead prove the statement

> Let $S$ be the set of adherent points of $A$. Then $S = \text{Cl} A$.

($\text{Cl} A$ contains $S$) Let $x$ be an adherent point of $A$. We want to show that $x \in \text{Cl} A$, so using your definition, we need to show that $x$ is contained in all the closed sets containing $A$. So, let $C$ be an arbitrary closed set containing $A$; then $X - C$ is an open set missing $A$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $x \in X - C$. Since $X - C$ is open, there would be a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U$ misses $C$, and since $A \subseteq C$, then $U$ also misses $A$. But this contradicts the hypothesis that $x$ is an adherent point of $A$. So we must have $x \in C$, and since $C$ was arbitrary, $x \in \text{Cl} A$.

($S$ contains $\text{Cl} A$) Let $x \in \text{Cl} A$. We want to show that $x$ is an adherent point of $A$. So, let $U$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $U$ is disjoint from $A$. Then $X - U$ is a closed set that contains $A$, and by hypothesis, we would have that $x \in X - U$, which contradicts the hypothesis that $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$. So, $U$ must intersect $A$. Since $U$ was arbitrary, $x$ is an adherent point of $A$.

Note that the concepts of "closure" and "adherent point" are not special to metric spaces. They apply to general topological spaces.